# How can I add a PropertyChangedCallback to a dependency-property of the base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, callback, dependency-properties

I have a class derived from System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, and I need to add a PropertyChangedCallback to the FrameworkElement.Margin dependency-property.

How is this accomplished from my C# code? I can't find any good examples of this in MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via calling [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata.aspx) in your UserControl.

This provides the means to merge PropertyChangedCallback characteristics.  For details, see the MSDN page for [Dependency Property Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752375.aspx#scenarios) (search for the section titled "Overriding Metadata").